# Rails upload a file and render it as an HTML page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a website with ROR 3. I need to provide a page to my clients wherein he could edit his pricing info regarding the application. I am quite confused on how to do this. The pricing page needs to be displayed as an html table with different columns which has got the pricing info.

I am thinking of different ways to do this.

1) Allow the client to create and upload an html page and then save it as a file in my public directory and render as an when the client clicks on the pricing link.

2) The clients may not have bare technical knowledge, hence make the client upload some other formats like Word, Excel etc and then parse it and store it as an HTML file in the public directory.

3) Provide the client with some real time editing tools where in the client could edit in a fixed format, and after wards save the file and render it later.

Also, I wouldn't like to store these infos in my database. There would be quite a few number of clients and hence managing all these data in my database would become cumbersome. Storing all these as plain html files and rendering it later would be the most ideal thing for me.

There might be other better steps in doing this as well. Could you please suggest which might the better, or any other option that could suit my needs? Basically I would want my clients to have a mechanism where they could provide there pricing details, edit it later and display it  back as an html table, all this **without** using an Database backend. Any suggestions would be mostly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Good way is Excel(csv format).

You can do PHP with Excel. I thing this is the best solutions for your requirement.

Try this.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: Hmm, I have thought of using the Database to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are give authority to user to change edit contain and you have to used " CSV or  Excel" please see these links:

- [Importing CSV and Excel](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel)
- [Exporting CSV and Excel](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel)

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to use database then you can use YAML as a structured storage.

e.g. ( you, most probably, could come up with a better structure )

```
SMS_Pack:
  Sl_No:
    1: 10000
    2: 25000
    3: 50000
```

You can read those .yml files and parse them as hashes. Should be fairly easy to represent that hash as a HTML table.

For the creation, I'm sure you can come up with some dynamic form input. Or to just let the client send this kind of file ( which might not be the best solution ).

But it just might be easier to manage all of this information within a database.